# Using a bash script on a Mac to connect to network shares?

Tags: bash, networking, mount

I'm using a Mac at work and would like some network shares mounting when i start the computer. Can i use a bash script (or similar) to connect and mount these shares? The shares are from both Windows and Mac servers and we usually connect using IP addresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check out [mount_smbfs](https://web.archive.org/web/20090827124708/http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/mount_smbfs.8.html), assuming that your network shares are smbfs/cifs.

```
mount_smbfs [-N] [-o options] [-d mode] [-f mode] [-h] //[domain;][user[:password]@]server[/share] path
```

I'm not intimately familiar with the OSX startup process, but it's possible you can create your shell-script as a program/folder in /Library/StartupItems or /System/Library/StartupItems

As mentioned on [osxbook.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20181226172724/http://osxbook.com/book/bonus/ancient/whatismacosx/arch_startup.html)

> /etc/rc finally launches
> /sbin/SystemStarter to handle startup
> items from locations such as
> /System/Library/StartupItems and
> /Library/StartupItems. A StartupItem
> is a program, usually a shell script,
> whose name matches the folder name.
> The folder contains a property list
> file containing key-value pairs such
> as Description, Provides, Requires,
> OrderPreference, start/stop messages
> etc. You can run SystemStarter -n -D
> as root to have the program print
> debugging and dependency information
> (without actually running anything).

Answer (score 1):

You can either do this via a Apple Script which you simple add to the User Startup Items, or do it via Automator and again add to Startup Items (System Prefs -> Users -> Startup Items), If you want to you can also just call a bash script from an AppleScript if you are more familier with Bash, but mounting shares is an easy task anyway. 
If you maybe like to mount them with a Keystroke, check out FastScript which lets you configure AppleScript Actions as Shortcuts.